# PTIJ: Addressing God properly

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Psalm 150 says:

> כֹּ֣ל הַ֭נְּשָׁמָה תְּהַלֵּ֥ל יָ֗הּ -- All that breathes praises ya

Isn't it a bit too familiar to address God as "ya"?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you know, this could really work as a serious question - why isn't Hashem's full name used here.

Answer (score 2):

It's teaching you, all things and people should praise God, even those that say ya.

Comment: I don't know what's going on, but stumbled upon another answer of yours today!

Comment: @RabbiKaii you might as well just press my name and see all the other juicy questions and answers i have.